# JavaScript Object Expected error in _doPostBack('','')

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I keep getting the '**Object Expected**' error within my page script when I click the button.
I've debugged using fire-bug and the id passed to the JavaScript method is the correct id and `document.getElementById(a)` finds the button. The error keeps occurring in the `_doPostBack`. Can this be caused because the button is inside a modal popup in a gridview cell, and the gridview is inside a update panel.

For complete code please see this previous question [event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969690/button-click-event-on-modal-popup-inside-a-grid-view-not-firing) I posted and resolved.

The reason I'm still using the JavaScript is the Post-Back event in the GridView.RowCommand did not occur without this.

Is there an alternative to this?

The code:

```
function addAcc(a) {
        var btn = document.getElementById(a); //get the button, not necessary but safer
        alert(a); //To see the button id
        _doPostBack(btn.id, ''); //do the postback so RowCommand Fires in code behind
    };
```

`<asp:Button ID="btnAddAcc" runat="server" Text="Add Account"` 
                                                        `OnClientClick="javascript:addAcc(this.id)" />`

Thank you for any solutions and ideas.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the dopostback method is with two underscores not one, like

```
__doPostBack
```

so your call is like:

```
__doPostBack(btn.id, '');
```

instead of

```
_doPostBack(btn.id, '');
```

Comment: Thanks.. I Feel like a newb now... Enjoy the day! Cheers

Comment: :) I was hoping that you haven't gone for some alternative solution as it was only a minor mistake. Cheers and have a good day